# Login java web con mysql netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, web, servlets

estoy intentando hacer un simple login con java web y mysql , recibo los datos desde mi index luego los envió a un servlet llamado "ValidaUsuario" , ahí creo un u nuevo usuario y llamo al método que valida  que el usuario este en la base de datos pero este siempre me arroja "False" incluso cuando le paso los datos correctos.

Aquí valido el usuario:

```
   public boolean Valida(String nom, String pass){
         boolean ok=false;
        Conexion conex=new Conexion();
       try { 
        String sql="SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Nombre = ? and Password = ?" ;
        conex.conectar();
        PreparedStatement st=(PreparedStatement) conex.getConexion().prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1,  nom);
        st.setString(2, pass);
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();

        if(rs.absolute(1)){
            ok=true;
         
        } 
        
        
        conex.desconectar();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
           
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        
    }
   
  return ok;
  
}
```

Y este es el codigo del servlets que recibe el Usuario y el password :

```
@WebServlet(name = "ValidaUsuario", urlPatterns = {"/ValidaUsuario"})
```

public class ValidaUsuario extends HttpServlet {

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            String usuario= request.getParameter("usuario");
            String pas = request.getParameter("password");
            Usuario usu=new Usuario();
            System.err.println(usuario);
            System.err.println(pas);
            if(usu.Valida(usuario, pas)){
                System.err.println(usu.Valida(usuario, pas));
            response.sendRedirect("Principal.jsp");
            }else{
            System.err.println(usu.Valida(usuario, pas));
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            
            }
        
        
    }
}
```

Ojala alguien me pueda orientar, ya he probado que los datos llegan al servlet y los recibo bien pero al moento de hacer la comprobacion siempre me arroja false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es evidente que el if no está funcionando pues es lo que define si "ok" es true o false, podrías cambiar la manera en la que está estructurado tu código para hacer lo siguiente:

1.- Crear un query que solo busque el nombre de usuario.
2.- Guardar la contraseña de aquel usuario en el result set.
3.- Comparar la contraseña del result set con el parámetro que le mandaste.

Quedaría algo así:

```
public boolean Valida(String nom, String pass){
     boolean ok=false;
     Conexion conex=new Conexion();
     try { 
     String sql="SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Nombre = '?' " ;
     conex.conectar();
     PreparedStatement st=(PreparedStatement) 

     conex.getConexion().prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1,  nom);
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();

        if(rs.getString("Password").equals("pass")){
            ok=true;
        } 
        
        
        conex.desconectar();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
           
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        
    }
   
  return ok;
  
}
```

Otra cosa que acabo de notar es que los datos que está metiendo el query no están entre apostrofes, es decir, tienes un comando así:

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Nombre = ? and Password = ?" ;
```

Cuando debería estar así: (Observa los signos de interrogación)

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Nombre = '?' and Password = '?'" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

El if de tu código nunca se cumple por lo que la variable ok siempre queda en false.

reemplaza el if(rs.absolute(1)) por if(rs.next())

Si lo analizas bien, al momento de consultar datos a la bd tienes la validación de que el usuario existe. Entonces si tu resultset trae 1 dato significa que el usuario es válido.

Saludos.